# two encrypting / hashing case, which one is best

Tags: cryptography, aes, pbkdf2

Thinking about these below two cases, which one is best and most secure one

1st case

```
//key1 generated from static salt and user password, because in case attacker don't know about source code (bad assumption, but still my assumption), attacker have only hashed or encrypted data + random generated salt
staticSalt = "StaticSalt"
key1 = pbkdf2(userPassword, staticSalt, iteration)

//key2 generated from key1 and randomSalt, this will be actual key to be used for encryption
randomSalt = GenerateRandomSalt()
key2 = pbkdf2(key1, randomSalt, iteration)

aes.Key = Key2
aes.IV = aes.GenerateIV()
```

or

2nd case

```
//directly generate key from randomSalt and password
randomSalt = GenerateRandomSalt()
key1 = pbkdf2(userPassword, randomSalt, iteration)

aes.Key = Key1
aes.IV = aes.GenerateIV()
```

My question is, is there any drawback in using 1st case, will it increasing or decreasing entropy, or making is less secure?

or 2nd case is far more better and secure way to do

Looking for answer from some crypto expert.

Comment: You're more likely to get a proper reply on this if you post it on http://crypto.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: What benefit is the extra step in case 1 supposed to provide? If it's just something you threw on top of the PBKDF2 algorithm with a vague idea like "more scrambling is better", it's not likely to help.

Answer (score 0):

This question is more appropriate for [Sec.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

If you are using this code to store passwords, see [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/41165) in particular on how to properly hash and store passwords.

---

The first case appears to add obscurity, instead of security. Which may actually decrease security in the long run, by increasing the attack area (i.e. more places for bugs to happen).

Remember, you [don't want to be a Dave](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/25585/41165).

Comment: Thanks for your both links, unfortunately I can not make your answer as helpful. But just wonder how instead of providng one more defence line, this will increase attack area and will become prone to more places for bugs to happen while prior one also using same recommended pbkdf2 method